# UISearchController Modal Presentation Style Error

Tags: swift, user-interface, ios12

I am adding a UISearchController to a UIStackView programmatically, which is embedded as a subview in a larger view, which I am adding to a UITableViewCell in a UITableViewController.

I set the UITableViewController as the search bar delegate, the updater delegate, and the search controller delegate.

However, when I add the UISearchController to the view, I get this error:

> UISearchController only supports modal presentation styles UIModalPresentationPopover, UIModalPresentationFormSheet and UIModalPresentationCustom

Then, when I play around with it a bit, and set this setting:

```
searchController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
```

I then get this error:

> Presenting UISearchController in a popover or form sheet while reusing the search origin as the search results destination makes little sense. Initialize UISearchController with a proper search results controller to present as a popover or in a form sheet

What do these errors mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
let searchController = UISearchController()
```

to

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: myViewController)
```

fixed the issue for me, where myViewController inherits from UIViewController.